# Reactive and concurrent game between two nods over the network

Tags: scala, akka, scala.js, stun, ice

I implemented two player pong game using scala and scalajs,sofar I can play as two players using 4 different keys and now I'm looking to run it between two pc over the network.Any suggestions for reactive and concurrent tools to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Perhaps, you would need [Reactive Streams](https://github.com/reactive-streams/reactive-streams-jvm) and their Back-pressure protocol to not crash the server, when clients send too many requests. Basically, you would be able to specify different strategies for your server event consumer.
2. Web-Socket would be handy as well. Your Scala.js code would send messages to server over WS

I would recommend Akka-Streams: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/server-side/websocket-support.html

or Http4s-fs2
https://github.com/http4s/http4s/blob/master/examples/blaze/src/main/scala/com/example/http4s/blaze/BlazeWebSocketExample.scala

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to do it peer-to-peer between the two PCs, the main issue is going to be discovery, and setting up the connection. For security reasons, it is hard to open a socket directly to a client machine, especially if they are both behind standard consumer routers. You may need a server to start the discovery process (or one of the PCs needs to open its firewall), and you may find it easier to route the communication through a server.

No simple answers here, and this isn't a Scala.js thing per se -- just lessons learned from building peer-to-peer games in the distant past. The network stack is the hard part...